# ruby 2.4.1 ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension

Tags: ruby, makefile, rubygems

I upgraded ruby from `2.1`.. to `2.4.1` on windows, and installed the msys2 toolkit.

however each time install a gem calling Makefile I am getting a `ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension`

```
c:\>gem install oj
Temporarily enhancing PATH for MSYS/MINGW...
Building native extensions. This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing oj
ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.
current directory: C:/tools/ruby24/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/oj-3.1.3/ext/oj
C:/tools/ruby24/bin/ruby.exe -r ./siteconf20170616-1724-1fw22px.rb extconf.rb
Creating Makefile for ruby version 2.4.1 on x64-mingw32
creating Makefile
extconf.rb:68:in ``': No such file or directory - make clean 
(Errno::ENOENT)
from extconf.rb:68:in `<main>'
extconf failed, exit code 1
```

I am also getting similar errors when installing some other gems like `json`